# Excel IF ignoring Value

Tags: excel

Most likely pretty straight forward this, but it's got me stumped.

I have a cell in Excel (say C1) which has a text value of "W0-1".  I then have a formula in cell D1 of

```
=MID(C1,2,1)
```

and a formula of

```
=MID(C1,4,1)
```

in cell E1.

This basically strips out the numeric values of the text into two new columns, of home goals and away goals.

I then have another column (column F) that i want to populate with 1 or 0 based on the values of D1 and E1 being above 0.  The formula I entered is :

```
=IF(AND(D1>0,E1>0),1,0)
```

however in the above case this returns 1, when it should return 0, as the value in D1 is 0.

It appears that the IF formula is not interpreting the value in D1 as 0.  If i manually enter the figures in D1 and E1 as 0 and 1 my IF formula works correctly, so is this something I am doing wrong in the MID formula?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work...

```
=IF(AND(D1<>"0",E1<>"0"),1,0)
```

The formulas are returning text and your IF() is lookiung for numbers.
This will work too,

```
=IF(AND(D1="1",E1="1"),1,0)
```

Answer (score 3):

It's possible that your D1 and E1 columns are all strings that are being saved.

Wrap your MID functions with a VALUE function to turn them into integers.

```
VALUE(MID(C1,2,1))
```

Comment: Sweet, worked a treat...forgot about the VALUE function, was messing with TEXT, which I now realise was making it worse.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

A small change in formula

```
Cell D1 = VALUE(MID(C1,2,1)) 
Cell E1 = VALUE(MID(C1,4,1))
```

Since function `MID(text,start_num,num_chars)` returns a string